# Why is there always a fire truck present before refuelling?

Tags: safety, ground-operations, refueling, firefighting

Whenever I fly within Europe, I notice there is always a fire truck present for refuelling before takeoff.

***Is this standard procedure for every flight in commercial aviation? If yes, is this a global thing or just a European one?***

Comment: The title is confusing. I think you are meaning "refuelling", not really "before take off", right?

Comment: But so my question, is this not frequent on other continents?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Refuelling occurs in a very short windows with budget airlines, so yes, it's usually minutes before takeoff

Comment: But before embarkation of most of the passengers (per evacuation rules). Or the presence of firefighter simplify rules of having passengers during refuel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know it is not mandated, but ICAO (for which many aviation authorities derive their regulations) states in Annex 14 Section 9.6 Ground servicing of aircraft:

> 9.6.1 Fire extinguishing equipment suitable for
>   at least initial intervention in the event of a fuel
>   fire and personnel trained in its use shall be
>   readily available during the ground servicing of
>   an aircraft, and there shall be a means of
>   quickly summoning the rescue and fire fighting service in the event
>   of a fire or major fuel spill.

and

> 9.6.2 When aircraft refuelling operations take
>   place while passengers are embarking, on
>   board or disembarking, ground equipment shall
>   be positioned so as to allow:
>    a) the use of a sufficient number of exits for
>   expeditious evacuation; and
>   b) a ready escape route from each of the exits
>   to be used in an emergency

So you've probably been more aware of this if you were actually on the aircraft as it is being refuelled.

Comment: I've never seen a fire truck on the ramp at a US airport unless there was an actual emergency, even while an aircraft is being fueled with passengers onboard, so perhaps "readily available" is interpreted differently in different places?

Comment: @StephenS, I think the difference in interpretation is in the "fire extinguishing equipment" part of the requirement.  Every time I've seen a plane being fueled in the US, there's been a rather large fire extinguisher nearby.